# Comando update para retirar acentos dos dados gravados?

Tags: mysql

Existe algum comando update para retirar acentos dos nomes salvos nas tabelas, ex:

`update paciente set 'Ã' = 'A'`

claro que o nome da coluna não é esse, só um exemplo.

Comment: Não. Voce teria que usar uma função. Por exemplo: `update tabela set coluna = TirarAcentos(coluna)`. Nessa função você trataria de substituir todos os caracteres necessários e retornar o texto com as substituições

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17045193/6840825

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `remove_accents`;

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `remove_accents`(`str` TEXT)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''

BEGIN

    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Š','S');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'š','s');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ð','Dj');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ž','Z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ž','z');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'À','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Á','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Â','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ã','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ä','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Å','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Æ','A');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ç','C');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'È','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'É','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ê','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ë','E');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ì','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Í','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Î','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ï','I');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ñ','N');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ò','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ó','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ô','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Õ','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ö','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ø','O');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ù','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ú','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Û','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ü','U');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Ý','Y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'Þ','B');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ß','Ss');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'à','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'á','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'â','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ã','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ä','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'å','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'æ','a');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ç','c');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'è','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'é','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ê','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ë','e');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ì','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'í','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'î','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ï','i');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ð','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ñ','n');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ò','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ó','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ô','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'õ','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ö','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ø','o');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ù','u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ú','u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'û','u');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ý','y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ý','y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'þ','b');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ÿ','y');
    SET str = REPLACE(str,'ƒ','f');


    RETURN str;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Deve-se usar assim:

`update tabela set coluna = remove_accents(coluna)`